# Hbase Upsert with Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

I have spark streaming job and in this some am doing some aggregation, now I want to insert that records into HBase but its not typical insert I want to do UPSERT if for rowkey is available than in column values sum(newvalue+oldvalue) should happen.
Does anybody share the pseudo code in java how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...

```
byte[] rowKey = null; // Provided
Table table = null; // Provided
long newValue = 1000; // Provided
byte[] FAMILY = new byte[]{0}; // Defined
byte[] QUALIFIER = new byte[]{1}; // Defined

try {
    Get get = new Get(rowKey);
    Result result = table.get(get);
    if (!result.isEmpty()) {
        Cell cell = result.getColumnLatestCell(FAMILY, QUALIFIER);
        newValue += Bytes.bytesToLong(cell.getValueArray(),cell.getValueOffset());
    }
    Put put = new Put(rowKey);
    put.addColumn(FAMILY,QUALIFIER,Bytes.toBytes(newValue));
    table.put(put);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle Exceptions...
}
```

We (Splice Machine[Open Source]) have some pretty cool tutorials using Spark Streaming to store data in HBase.

Check [it](http://community.splicemachine.com/community/tutorials/) out. might be interesting.

Comment: Also, you might want to consider an HBase increment depending on the type you are adding...

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your reply its working but taking time for 500 mb its taking around 1hr in spark is there any way you know about the bulk update kind of thing?

Comment: I am exploring Splice Machine, also attended webinar of "Lambda-in-a-box" and sent one email to "Thomas Ryan" and waiting for his reply, I appreciate Splice Machine's work, can you please tell me which tutorial I should check because I have checked many but couldn't find any specific one. Again Thanks a ton....

Comment: Here is the video...http://community.splicemachine.com/splice-machine-tutorial-video-configuring-kafka-feed-splice-machine-part/

Comment: Here is the code https://github.com/splicemachine/splice-community-sample-code/tree/master/tutorial-kafka-spark-streaming

Answer (score 0):

I found the way below are the pseudo code:-

```
===========For UPSERT(Update and Insert)===========

public void HbaseUpsert(JavaRDD < Row > javaRDD) throws IOException, ServiceException {

         JavaPairRDD < ImmutableBytesWritable, Put > hbasePuts1 = javaRDD.mapToPair(

          new PairFunction < Row, ImmutableBytesWritable, Put > () {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public Tuple2 < ImmutableBytesWritable, Put > call(Row row) throws Exception {

                if(HbaseConfigurationReader.getInstance()!=null)
                {
                HTable table = new HTable(HbaseConfigurationReader.getInstance().initializeHbaseConfiguration(), "TEST");

            try {

               String Column1 = row.getString(1);
               long Column2 = row.getLong(2); 
               Get get = new Get(Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(0)));  
                   Result result = table.get(get);
                   if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                       Cell cell = result.getColumnLatestCell(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("Column2"));
                       Column2 += Bytes.toLong(cell.getValueArray(),cell.getValueOffset());
                     }
                Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(row.getString(0)));
                put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("Column1"), Bytes.toBytes(Column1));
                put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"), Bytes.toBytes("Column2"), Bytes.toBytes(Column2));
                return new Tuple2 < ImmutableBytesWritable, Put > (new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                table.close();
            }
                }
            return null;
           }
          });

         hbasePuts1.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(HbaseConfigurationReader.initializeHbaseConfiguration());

        }

==============For Configuration===============
public class HbaseConfigurationReader implements Serializable{

    static Job newAPIJobConfiguration1 =null;
    private static Configuration conf =null;
    private static HTable table= null; 
    private static HbaseConfigurationReader instance= null;

    private static Log logger= LogFactory.getLog(HbaseConfigurationReader.class);


HbaseConfigurationReader() throws MasterNotRunningException, ZooKeeperConnectionException, ServiceException, IOException{
    initializeHbaseConfiguration();
}

public static HbaseConfigurationReader getInstance() throws MasterNotRunningException, ZooKeeperConnectionException, ServiceException, IOException {

    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new HbaseConfigurationReader();
    }

    return instance;
}
public static Configuration initializeHbaseConfiguration() throws MasterNotRunningException, ZooKeeperConnectionException, ServiceException, IOException {
     if(conf==null)
     {
        conf=HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);
        table = new HTable(conf, "TEST");
         conf.set(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, "TEST");
        try {
            newAPIJobConfiguration1 = Job.getInstance(conf);
            newAPIJobConfiguration1.getConfiguration().set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "TEST");
            newAPIJobConfiguration1.setOutputFormatClass(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

     }

     else
         logger.info("Configuration comes null"); 

    return newAPIJobConfiguration1.getConfiguration();
 }
}
```